# In what circumstances can we replace the max operator with random selection in the DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

In the original DQN paper, gradients during training are derived as follows:

$\nabla_{\theta_i} L_i\left(\theta_i\right)=\mathbb{E}_{s, a \sim \rho(\cdot) ; s^{\prime} \sim \mathcal{E}}\left[\left(r+\gamma \max _{a^{\prime}} Q\left(s^{\prime}, a^{\prime} ; \theta_{i-1}\right)-Q\left(s, a ; \theta_i\right)\right) \nabla_{\theta_i} Q\left(s, a ; \theta_i\right)\right]$.

However, I find that replacing the max operator with a random selection works just as well. In what circumstances might this hold?

Comment: So, basically, you're using a random policy to select an action from $s'$? It might be a good idea to provide more context about your specific problem and what you mean by "works just as well".

Comment: Instead of computing all $Q(s^{\prime}, a^{\prime})$ and taking the largest of those values, I find that computing the value for a single randomly selected $a^{\prime}$ works just as well.